# Getting a can't convert Symbol into Integer error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to pass the following line to the find method

```
query = "?name=#{CGI.escape(name)}&limit=#{limit}#{offset}"


def find(opts = {},limit,offset)

      if opts[:query].nil? || opts[:query].empty?
        return Net::HTTPNotFound
      end
      path = '/'
      if opts[:query]
      path << "?#{opts[:query]}"
      path << "&limit=#{limit}" 
      path << "&offset=#{offset}"
```

I seem to get a can't convert Symbol into Integer when i do a opts[:query]. How can i get by this issue?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call `find`?

Comment: response = query_account(query,limit,offset)

Answer (score 0):

The method assumes that opts is a `Hash` when it's really a `String`

One way of fixing is to call the `query_account` method like:

```
response = query_account({:query => query},limit,offset)
```

Or change the method to work with `query` directly.